# Issue with IE developer toolbar

Tags: internet-explorer, ie-developer-tools

I have just installed IE developer toolbar to debug my website in IE but I cant't see the content of javascript script codes on the page.

How can I see the js script content like firebug?

Answer (score 0):

It's in the Script tab, beside HTML | CSS

Comment: For mine, the HTML | CSS is just below the Find | File | View